# Infragistics - No License information found - False error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, infragistics

In Visual Studio 2010 ult - 2012 ult - 2013 pro

In XAML my infragistics controls are underlined by intelesense and the error reads

> "No License information found"

This is not the case however.

My app builds and works just fine. I don't know why I ALWAYS get this error.

Im using WPF4 infragistics 11.2

Is there any way to disable this in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed NetAdvantage product?  If so then you shouldn't be getting this error and you should send Infragistics Support a log file from the installation they can review to see what has happened.  If not, then you need to install the product.

Comment: I do have NetAdvantage installed. I didn't install any of these tools it was handled when I got my dev machine so I cant say that it is done correct or not. Does it make a difference that we have a build server separate from my machine?

Comment: If the error is on your machine, then the product needs to be installed there or it is possible that something is missing from the installation and you would need to send a log file to Infragistics Support.  Note that the log files should have automatically been created by the installer and if you don't have that, you may need to run the installer again to generate a log file (which may also resolve the issue if there was an issue with the installation).  As far as the separate build server see http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/12859.aspx

Comment: Now maybe you can answer this question too haha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490696/creating-an-infragistics-xamdatachart-programatically-with-multiple-columnseries